# Multiple condition IF query in SQL Query Table

Tags: sql, zoho

I am trying to create a query table using SQL on which I will build a pivot table in a dashboard and I have the following query:

```
     SELECT
        "Owner",
        "Meetings",
        "No Meeting Reason",
     FROM  Investors
```

The *Owner* is a full name, the *Meetings?* is a Yes/No entry and the *No Meeting Reason* is a list of values: '**Not Yet Started**', '**No Meeting(s) This Month**', '**Awaiting Details Publish**' and a NULL value.

Basically, what I am trying to do is use IF queries so I can create the following columns:

- *Confirmed Meeting*: if *Meetings?* is 'Yes', the value is 1, if not 0
- *No Meeting*: if *Meetings?* is 'No' AND *No Meeting Reason* is **No Meeting(s) This Month**, the value is 1, if not 0
- *Not Complete*: if *Meetings?* is 'No' AND *No Meeting Reason* is '**Not Yet Started**', '**Awaiting Details Publish**' or **NULL**, value is 1, if not 0

How do I do this in my query? I know the first one is probably

```
IF("Meetings?" = 'Yes',1,0) 'Confirmed Meeting'
```

Thanks in advance for any support.

**** EDIT ****

So I used CASE WHEN as recommended to change this, however, when I should get *Not Complete* = 1 every time *Confirmed Meeting* and *No Meeting* are = 0

(because it is: if *Meetings?* is 'No' AND *No Meeting Reason* is anything other than **No Meeting(s) This Month**)

I did not get that so how would I construct a nested CASE WHEN statement for:
If 'Confirmed Meeting' and 'No Meeting' are both not 0 then 'Not Complete' is 1?

Comment: Welcome! You're looking for the CASE statement, you can read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like this.

```
SELECT
    "Owner",
    "Meetings",
    "No Meeting Reason",
    case when "Meetings"='Yes' then 1 
         else 0
         end  as "Confirmed Meeting",
         
    case when "Meetings"='No' and "No Meeting Reason" ='No Meeting(s) This Month' then 1
         else 0 
         end as "No Meeting",
   case  when "Meetings"='No' and nvl("No Meeting Reason",'x') in ('Not Yet Started','Awaiting Details Publish','x') then 1
         else 0
         end as "Not Complete"
 FROM  Investors;
```

Comment: Hi Alok, I have found a new problem based on this response. Could you check again?

Comment: What problem are you facing now ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` for such requests. Though I do not understand the data type of `"No Meeting Reason"` whether it is a string or a nested column with a list and which database you currently use.

```
SELECT
        "Owner",
        "Meetings",
        "No Meeting Reason",
        CASE
            WHEN "Meetings" = 'Yes' THEN 1 
            ELSE 0
        END AS "Confirmed Meeting",
        CASE
            WHEN "Meetings" = 'No' AND "No Meeting Reason" = 'No Meeting(s) This Month' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS "No Meeting",
        CASE
            WHEN "Meetings" = 'No' AND "No Meeting Reason" IN ('Not Yet Started, Awaiting Details Publish', NULL) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS "Not Complete"
FROM  Investors
```

For your edited part, meaning that both confirmed meeting and no meeting are both not 0; meeting can be both 'Yes' or 'No' and no meeting reason must be 'No Meeting(s) This Month'. Just add such condition in `"Not Complete"` column.

```
SELECT
    "Owner",
    "Meetings",
    "No Meeting Reason",
    CASE
        WHEN "Meetings" = 'Yes' THEN 1 
        ELSE 0
    END AS "Confirmed Meeting",
    CASE
        WHEN "Meetings" = 'No' AND "No Meeting Reason" = 'No Meeting(s) This Month' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS "No Meeting",
    CASE
        WHEN "Meetings" IN ('Yes', 'No') AND "No Meeting Reason" = 'No Meeting(s) This Month' THEN 1
        WHEN "Meetings" = 'No' AND "No Meeting Reason" IN ('Not Yet Started, Awaiting Details Publish', NULL) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS "Not Complete"
FROM  Investors
```

Comment: Hi, it is a string data type from a dropdown list in a front-end form

Comment: Okay, please try the query or the one @Alok just posted.

Comment: Hi @highlytrainedbadger based on your query, it worked, except for the 'No Meeting' query column. Could you review the edits I made to the OP and see if there is an alternative solution

Comment: Check out the edited part for your request. Just a line added to column "Not Complete".

Answer (score 0):

In `SQL Server` you can use `IIF` like this:

```sql
SELECT IIF(500<1000, 'YES', 'NO');
```

I'm not sure whether this feature is also supported by `zoho` or not. I couldn't find any resources for that so I couldn't test it.